# How to build a neural networks model to classify data in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to build a model to classify some data (4 classes). 
here is what I have tried out:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense


# dividing X, y into train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_data, y_target, random_state=0)

# define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=9, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax')) 
# compile model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the model on the dataset
train_history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=20, verbose=0, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
# evaluate the keras model
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_data, y_target, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %.3f' % (accuracy*100))
```

I get this error :

```
Received a label value of 4 which is outside the valid range of [0, 4).
```

Could someone please help me understand what is wrong with my model ?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: what data do you use ? Do you use labels `0,1,2,3` or `1,2,3,4` ? Model expects labels `0,1,2,3` but it gets `4`

Comment: Thank you @furas . It works when I change the last layer to 5. Which means, I guess, it starts counting from 0 until 4. (1) How can I get the confusion matrix from it, so that I can see the output array ? (2) If it was a single class, I would have given 1 in the last layer, and not 0. So, why does it work with the last layer having a value of 5, when I have 4 classes ?

Comment: I used labels 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: you will have to change to `0,1,2,4` but with pandas it is not problem - `df["label"] = df["label"] - 1`

Comment: Thank you @furas , it has solved my problem.

Comment: Please, either take the time to self-answer, or else delete this, since it appears as still open/unanswered and people spend time looking into it - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @furas , I solved my problem, by changing the labels from `[1 2 3 4]` to `[0 1 2 3]` with pandas: `df["label"] = df["label"] - 1`

Answer (score -1):

Actually if you would have split the data from the same frame using `train_test_split`, then this error should not have come. Please check the data again. Also make sure to use `stratify`option in `train_test_split`.